# Не работает get-запрос

Tags: javascript, jquery

Необходимо получить json данные с сайта[image: введите сюда описание изображения] но с помощью $.get получить данные не получается , по причине отсутствия заголовка CORS
Хотя и получается получить данные с помощью file_get_contents
Как можно решить проблему?

Answer (score 1):

```
$.get("myscript.php", function(data) {
   ...
});
```

myscript.php:

```
<?php
  echo file_get_contents(...);
?>
```